# How to translate the meaning of the german phrase "Leider geil"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, german

"Leider geil" is a song by german hiphop band "Deichkind" and mentions things that are sadly cool, like buying new cars very frequently even though thats bad for the environment or finally getting a new job but have to many drinks at the bar the day before the job starts.. 
I find it difficult to translate "leider" as to me it means both sadly and unfortunately combined, also "geil" is difficult to translate as in german its meaning developed from purely sexual to occasionally sexual but mostly describes something awesome that excites you. Here I would go with awesome but neither sadly awesome nor unfortunatly awesome sound complete to me.

Thank you for taking the time and reading this. I don't know if this is the right place for such a question.

Comment: Like a vice? ? ?

Comment: "Sadly cool" (or rather "sadly awesome", but that one doesn't fit the metre) is perfectly fine. That is exactly what it means. Of course it won't work at that one point in the song where *geil* is used in the meaning "horny" (*ich war wohl gestern abend leider geil*). But that's word games and poetry translation for you. A fascinating puzzle with no solution. Shrug.

Comment: Regrettably fantastic/superb...